# Number of times that a word appears in a list of words haskell

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, tuples

I just started programming in Haskell and I want to create a function takes a list of words and a list of letters, that afterwards turns into a matrix of letters like a words search puzzle, and returns which words of that list of words occurs in the matrix along with how many times it occurs, returning those informations in a tuple.

I already have the function for the word search, I just couldn't find a way of writing one for 
the times of occurrences.

I would appreciate a little help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function you could make use of:

```
find :: (Eq a, Enum e) => a -> [a] -> e
find _ []     = toEnum 0
find y (x:xs) = (if y == x then succ else id) $ find y xs
```

Comment: ``find 3 [1,2,3]`` throws an error: "no instance for (Enum e0) arising from the use of ``find``. The type variable ``e0`` is ambiguous"

Comment: @ThreeFx Did you give it a specific return type?  That function works fine for me, but I have to give it an explicit return type like `find 3 [1, 2, 3] :: Int` so that the compiler knows which `Enum` instance to use.

Comment: @bheklilr lol I completely forgot about that :D Everything works fine. But why not do ``find :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int``?

Comment: @ThreeFix  Specializing to be`Int ` would be limiting. What if you want to use lazy peano numbers? Or unbounded `Integer`? Or you were going to use it in floating number calculation?

Comment: does anyone know how can I change that function so it returns how many times a word appears in a list of lists like ["skjnkjsfngjfd","sgniurnguerng"]?

Comment: @PyRules That find function returns the number of times a word appears in a lists of words, but I need it to return the number of times that a word appears in a lists of "random words", like "coffee" ["jdsnffncoffeehjbjhb", "dsnfkjsdnfkjds"] = 1. I tried to change it to do that but it isn't working :(

Comment: @emic That would probably be good for a sperate question, as it is quite different.

Comment: @PyRules I have a function that verifies if a word is a sublist of a list, so if it was (sublist "coffee" "jdsnffncoffeehjbjhb") it would come out True. So I tried to do:
find _ []    = toEnum 0
find y (x:xs) = (if (sublist y x) then succ else id) $ nv y xs but I'm getting and error " No instance for (Enum a10) arising from a use of `nv'"

Comment: @PyRules it's a word search puzzle :)

Comment: @PyRulez Sorry, I changed the function's name and forgot to replace it . num :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
num _ []     = toEnum 0
num y (x:xs) = (if (sublista y x) then succ else id) $ num y xs. I got the error "Could not deduce (a ~ [a0])
    from the context (Eq a)
      bound by the type signature for num :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int"